# RabbitMQ stops publishing/ consuming messages abruptly

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ version: 3.8.2
Erlang 22.2

I have a WebAPI which is publishing messages to RabbitMQ. Every time I reinstall the rabbitMQ on the server, it works fine for a couple of days and then abruptly stops working(publishing messages to the RabbitMQ)

Upon checking the logs, the following are the errors I get:

1. emulator Discarding message{'$gen_cast',{force_event_refresh.#Ref<0.2351292273.2653945857.145257>}} from <0.319.0> to <0.6433.4> in an old incarnation(1) of this node (2)
2. Error on AMQP connection <0.22083.0> ([::1]:5672, user: 'username' state:opening)
3. Could not find handle.exe, please install from sysinternals

My rabbitMQ log is filled with multiple instances of each of the above errors. Could you please help?

*Let me know what additional information would you need to identify the root cause of the issue. I am unable to add code/ log snippets right now due to unavoidable circumstances